# loading select2 control from another page giving me troubles

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using the following piece of code to try and load one page from another so i can show the 2nd page html inside a dialog:

```
 var $link = $('#addTagButton');
        var $dialog = $('#addTag')
                .load($link.attr('href'))
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 600
                });
        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
```

However, when it come to load the select2 control on the 2nd page it doesn't recognize the select2 option and basically doesn't load its functionality. i have a reference to the select2.js in both pages and everything else is working perfectly but there.

1. does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?
2. is there any better way to load one page from another and get it to work?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

"load one page from another" is a bit worrying.

The general principles are as follows :

- `.load(...)` should load a valid HTML fragment, not a whole page
- In general, javascript associated with the loaded fragment will be present on the host page (page 1). If you know what you are doing, you *can* load script blocks with the HTML fragment, and a measure of control can be exercised to determine whether the scripts are executed or not - see the "Script Execution" section [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
- Handlers for events that do not bubble (eg. a select element's 'onchange' event) must be attached to elements after the fragment has loaded
- Handlers for events that bubble (eg. 'mouseover', 'click') can often be delegated to static container(s) on the host page such that they will operate on existing and future contained elements.

See [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the nuts and bolts of attaching event handlers.

Comment: From the documentation for .load() (http://api.jquery.com/load/), it looks like you can load scripts  along with the HTML (see the section labeled "Script Execution".

Comment: Thanks for that EZ. I have edited the second bullet point in my answer. Do you think what I now say is fair?